# Vue js in laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'll post the code, I can't store the data in the tweets array, where am I wrong? i am using vue and laravel

```
<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
         this.recupera_post()
        },
   
    data(){ 
        return{
             tweets:[]
        }
       
    },
    methods:{
        async recupera_post(){
            await axios.get('api/schedulepost')
            .then(function(response){
                console.log(response.data)
                app.tweets=response.data
                })
            }
        }
    }
    
</script>
```

Comment: What is the error ? be more specific

Comment: no errors, just don't populate the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just need to write `this.tweets` also you need to change your callback function to arrow function to allow you to access your state like this

```js
 async recupera_post(){
     await axios.get('api/schedulepost')
     .then((response) => {
       console.log(response.data)
       this.tweets = response.data
     })
  }
}
```

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'tweets')

Comment: change the callback function to arrow function

Comment: @carulom check the answer i update it